# How does [RemoteClass] work in Flex Actionscript can I use it for custom data-binding?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript, remoting, blazeds

Actionscript supports a [RemoteClass] metadata tag that is used in BlazeDS to provide data-binding hints for marshalling AMF binary objects from Java to BlazeDS.

For example:

**Java:**
    package sample;

```
public class UserInfo
{
    private String userName;

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String value)
    {
        userName = value;
    }
}
```

**Actionscript:**

```
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="sample.UserInfo")]
public class UserInfo
{
    public var userName:String=”";
}
```

How exactly is the [RemoteClass] implemented in the BlazeDS framework and could you override that behavior and provide a custom data-binding remoting framework (e.g. a JSON message passing system) that you could bind to the Actionscript [Bindable], [RemoteClass] class?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[RemoteClass(alias="com.example.MyClass")] is a Flex shorthand for calling [flash.net.registerClassAlias()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias%28%29) :

```
public function registerClassAlias(aliasName:String, classObject:Class):void
```

To access those registered alias classes at runtime (to write a custom JSON data serialization framework) you can call:

[getClassByAlias](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/package.html#getClassByAlias())(aliasName:String):Class
Looks up a class that previously had an alias registered through a call to the registerClassAlias() method.

For outgoing encoding from AS to Java you need to retrieve the aliased class name, you can do that by calling [flash.utils.describeType()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()) and use "reflection" on your Actionscript object's class to query attributes, properties, methods of the object.

For example the following code snippet for [ObjectCodec.as](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=7&ct=rc#a2tKkY7STZE/trunk/ygg/encoding/amf/type/v3/ObjectCodec.as&q=lang:actionscript%20describeType&exact_package=http://yggsaw.googlecode.com/svn) seems to retrieve the alias attribute by using "@":

```
override protected function encodeComplex(o:Object, b:IBinary, context:IContext=null):void
{
        var desc:XML = describeType(o);
        var classAlias:String = desc.@alias;
        //...
}
```

Comment: Adobe's site no longer has information on the `registerClassAlias` method; there's [a post on the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1012207?start=0&tstart=0) disuccsing the missing documentation.

Comment: @supervacuo: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias%28%29

Answer (score 2):

[RemoteClass] is only used on the Flex side.  All it really does is call the [flash.net.registerClassAlias()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias()) function to setup a mapping between a local object and a remote class name.

Comment: So is there a way to access the flash.net.registerClassAlias() list. I'm trying to write my own custom remoting using JSON messages so I'm not using Flex's Producer/Consumer or IDataInput, IDataOutput interfaces.

I need to be able to lookup a Flex class from a remote java class name and construct it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `-keep-generated-actionscript` compiler argument to see what code is generated and how it works exactly.