# Blaze DS custom marshaled object in Java end

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

I have an arraylist of custom object in servlet end. I want to send it back to flex end as custom marshaling through BlazeDs (as my web project holds blazeDS settings) so flex end can get ArrayCollection objects. How do I do that? I can get String or json arrays, but I dont want that, what I want is custom marshaled object thorugh blaze DS, how do I do that?

Comment: Use RemoteObject through your BlazeDS AMF Gateway

Comment: I used remote object for sending flex object to java end and it worked fine, but when I send java object to flex end it only receives object type as string.

Comment: That is unexpected; are you sending back a string or an object?  I think you'lll need to share some code on the Java side to show how you are returning values.

Comment: PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); ASTranslator ast = new ASTranslator();  out.print(ast.convert(ObjSalesReview, flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection.class));
         out.flush(); [ObjSalesReview is arraylist containing custom object]

Comment: Edit your question and add the code to your question.  Code in comments is hard to read.  Doesn't Java have the concept of a "return" like ActionScript does?  I assume you have to 'return' your object.  I also assume that "out.print" and "out.flush" are used for displaying data--such as to a console or a web page--not for returning values from a method.  [I'm not a Java expert, though]

Answer (score 0):

Use [RemoteClass(alias="")] metadata tag to represent server-side Java Object at flex end.
The same question is asked and perfectly answered at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671668/how-does-remoteclass-work-in-flex-actionscript-can-i-use-it-for-custom-data-bi).

[How does [RemoteClass] work in Flex Actionscript can I use it for custom data-binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671668/how-does-remoteclass-work-in-flex-actionscript-can-i-use-it-for-custom-data-bi)

Comment: this was already written [Bindable]
 [RemoteClass(alias="com.rit.subarubmwebjava.vo.SalesReviewOneAnswerVO")]